# In Java, why does @Nullable have runtime rentention

Tags: java, annotations, nullable, static-analysis

As the title says, having @Nullable and @Nonull can help your ide or linter catch bugs at compile time, but why does it have runtime retention?

Comment: Maybe it prevents NPEs by convincing the runtime that no, really, this reference isn't null. ;)

Comment: For @Nullable it means if you override the method, the override should also accept null values.  To implement that, the annotation should have at least class retention.  This comment is a partial answer.

Comment: @emory How does class retention help in the case of overriding an annotated method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if @Nullable is retained at the source level, I write `void m (@Nullable p)`, and compile it, then there would be no trace of the annotation in the class file.  You obtain the class file and put it in your class path, extend my class, and overwrite my method.  How does your ide or linter know about my annotation?

Answer (score 5):

Conceivably, runtime retention would allow an AOP proxy to detect null arguments being passed to a `@Nonnull`-annotated parameter, and throw an exception or otherwise handle it. You could argue that this is a nicer way of handling runtime null checking that using an explicit null check in the code.

Yes, these annotations are very useful for static compile checking, but there's no reason they couldn't be used at runtime for the same purpose. Their validity as annotations extends into the runtime domain, unlike annotations that are used for things like code generation.